# Is it possible to make an exe from a string?

Tags: string, exe, execute

I came across this idea that you maybe can make an exe from a long string. Because if you open an exe in a text editor like notepad you get all these strange letters. Now i wonder if you can copy those letters and make a program that creates a text file and add .exe at the end and then execute it. Does this work or is it gonna become destroyed?

Comment: Not really. The editor is doing its best to interpret the file's bytes as character data, but that doesn't mean that it's all valid character data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXE files in Windows are executable files. They are compiled binary files that don't contain specifically letters, words or sentences for humans to interpret, but instruction for the processor to perform. Every different processor (type) has another language in which the programmer has to speak to. This "language" is called "Assembly" and it's the lowest level language in which a programmer can contact a processor.

When opening an EXE file, you notice a ton of gibberish. That is not gibberish, that is the processor's language interpreted from its binary values to the text editor's chosen text encoding (e.g. ASCII, Unicode..).

So, the answer is: No, or at the very least unlikely.

BTW, notice that every EXE file starts with what appears to be the two letters `MZ`, which in the UTF-8 encoding (ASCII) they have the same binary values of the two bytes of the EXE file's header.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking can you write a program that contains inside it a valid exe binary in an array, write that to a file and execute it, then the answer is yes.

Comment: So if I get the valid binary data from the exe and make a file and end with .exe it will work?